# Completely new to GIS, how do I extract the pic of a certain elevation from the ETOPO .tiff file

Tags: mapping, topography, bathymetry

So I started learning QGIS a week ago to do an alt-geo map and .tiff files from what I have read contain several image files displayed as 1.

Is there a way for me to export specifically the PNG that corresponds to a specific elevation?.

Because a friend of mine on the same project can do something rougher version of that on GIMP and my attempts to do that on GIMP don't work(it just opens the current elevation pic in the .tiff) while QGIS can open it fully for me and QGIS is more made for that specific purpose.

https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/products/etopo-global-relief-model